# When the "Documentation" review queue is cleared, it shows a different message than the other queues

Tags: feature-request, documentation, review-queues

When reviewing "First posts" and "Late Answers" queues, and the queue is cleared the following message is displayed:

[image: Queue cleared message]

However, when the "Documentation" queue is cleared, this one is displayed:

[image: Different queue cleared message]

It's not a big deal, however it is inconsistent and also lacks the "view all review queues" link which I usually use for the other queues which is mildly annoying.

Will this minor annoyance get any attention?

Comment: There is always the "Review" hyperlink in the upper left which can take you back to the review queues page.

Comment: Yeah, I use that, but as I said it's *mildly annoying*.

Comment: Everything about Docs review is inconsistent in some fashion with /review, all the way down to the URL structure.